Map defined by matrix units.
If $\{|\alpha_i\rangle\}_{i=1}^m$ and $\{| \beta_k \rangle\}_{k=1}^n$ are orthonormal bases of subsystems $A$ and $B$ respectively of a Hilbert space $H = A \otimes B$ and
$$P_{kl} = |\alpha_k\rangle\langle\alpha_l| \otimes 1_B$$
is a family of matrix units, then what can we say about the map
$$\Gamma(\rho) = \sum_{k,l} P_{kl}\rho P_{kl}^*?$$

It is a completely positive map. If you normalize it by dividing by $n$, then you also get unital and trace-preserving.

Thank you! I'm trying to prove
$$\Gamma(\rho) = \sum_{k,l} P_{kl}\rho P_{kl}^* = 1_A \otimes (\operatorname{Tr}A \circ\ \mathcal{P})(\rho)$$
where
$$\mathcal{P}(\rho) = \sum{k=1}^m P_{kk}(\rho)\sum_{k=1}^m P_{kk}.$$
It feels like it should be very straightforward, but I'm having a hard time seeing what is happening. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

What do you mean by $P_{kk}(\rho)$? I thought $\rho$ is a (density) matrix on $A \otimes B$?

Possibly the correct statement has no brackets?

``Define the projection $P_\mathfrak{A} = P_{11} + \dotsb + P_{mm}$ so that $P_\mathfrak{A}H = A \otimes B$. Define a superoperator $\mathcal{P}\mathfrak{A}(\cdot) = P\mathfrak{A}(\cdot)P_\mathfrak{A}$."

Lemma 2.1 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0504189

Uh, now I know what’s going on. I didn’t realize this, but $\Gamma$ is literally just the partial trace $\text{Tr}_A$. The only reason the paper defines the additional operator $\mathcal{P}$ is because the Hilbert space has an additional direct summand $K$. $P$ is just projection onto $A \otimes B$, so $\mathcal{P}$ is just cutting off the part of $\rho$ on $K$. That’s all.

I see! Thank you, that is very helpful! :)

(In your formula for $\mathcal{P}$, you wrote the same index $k$ twice. It should have been $k$ and $k’$. In your case $H = A \otimes B$, $P$ just equals $1_A \otimes 1_B$ and $\mathcal{P}$ is just the identity operator.)

Disregarding that there was a projection $\mathcal P$ hidden here (the purpose of which is to get rid of an additional direct summand of the Hilbert space, as clarified in the comments) let me quickly show that $\sum_{k,l}P_{kl}\rho P_{kl}^*$ as a mapping from $A\otimes B$ to $A\otimes B$ is just the partial trace over $A$ following by the extension by ${\bf1}_A$, as suspected. For this we decompose
\begin{align*}
\Psi:=\sum_{k,l}P_{kl}\rho P_{kl}^* &=\sum_{k,l}(|\alpha_k\rangle\langle\alpha_l|\otimes{\bf1})\rho(|\alpha_l\rangle\langle\alpha_k|\otimes{\bf1})\\
&=\sum_{k,l}(|\alpha_k\rangle\otimes{\bf1})(\langle\alpha_l|\otimes{\bf1})\rho(|\alpha_l\rangle\otimes{\bf1})(\langle\alpha_k|\otimes{\bf1})
\end{align*}
which implies $\Psi=\Phi_1\circ\Phi_2$ where $\Phi_1=\sum_{k}(|\alpha_k\rangle\otimes{\bf1})(\cdot)(\langle\alpha_k|\otimes{\bf1})$ and $\Phi_2=\sum_{l}(\langle\alpha_l|\otimes{\bf1})(\cdot)(|\alpha_l\rangle\otimes{\bf1})$. All we need now are the following three basic insights:

$\Phi_1(\rho_B)={\bf1}_A\otimes\rho_B$. Because $|\alpha_k\rangle\otimes{\bf1}$  is defined to act like $(|\alpha_k\rangle\otimes{\bf1})|x\rangle=|\alpha_k\rangle\otimes|x\rangle$ we for all $x,y\in B$ find
\begin{align*}
\Phi_1(|x\rangle\langle y|)&=\sum_{k}(|\alpha_k\rangle\otimes{\bf1})(|x\rangle\langle y|)(\langle\alpha_k|\otimes{\bf1})\\
&=\sum_{k}(|\alpha_k\rangle\otimes|x\rangle)(\langle\alpha_k|\otimes \langle y|)\\
&=\Big(\sum_{k}|\alpha_k\rangle\langle\alpha_k|\Big)\otimes|x\rangle\langle y|={\bf1}_A\otimes|x\rangle\langle y|\,.
\end{align*}
In this last step we used the decomposition of the identity matrix into any orthonormal basis. Now because $\Phi_1={\bf1}_A\otimes(\cdot)$ on all rank-1 matrices, this equality extends to all matrices by simple linearity
$\Phi_2=\Phi_1^*$ where $\Phi^*_1$ is the (Hilbert-Schmidt) dual map of $\Phi_1$. The follows at once because the Kraus operators of $\Phi_2$ are the adjoint of the Kraus operators of $\Phi_1$: $$(|\alpha_k\rangle\otimes{\bf1})^*=|\alpha_k\rangle^*\otimes{\bf1}^*=\langle\alpha_k|\otimes{\bf1}$$
$\Phi_2={\rm tr}_A$: Sometimes, the partial trace is even defined as the dual of the extension map $X\mapsto X\otimes{\bf1}$, cf. also this post

Altogether, this shows $\Psi(\rho)=\sum_{k,l}P_{kl}\rho P_{kl}^*={\bf1}\otimes {\rm tr}_A(\rho)$ for all $\rho$ as desired.
